# not able to access tomcat from webbrowser

Tags: tomcat

i installed tomcat9 on the server, but i am not able to access it from the webbrowser.
it says connection refused.

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 8081
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

i tried changing the default port 8080 to 8081 in the server.xml file but it does not seem to work.
i tried checking for any other instance using port 8080 but that also does not solve the issue.
this is what i see in catalina logs

```
18-Jan-2018 19:26:53.567 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:866)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:575)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:944)
        ... 13 more
```

what else can i check here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

On your localhost and port 8080 is currently running an application. Probably any instance of web server. You can check it on Linux/Unix with

> netstat -lnp

in the line where you will find port 8080 there is a proces number that occupies this port. Kill this process and start your server

Comment: Do you get the message "address already in use"?
Can you post the output of netstat -lnp ?